# Relationship between primitive and differential

Tags: calculus

Using the 'definition' primitive as: «g(x) is a primitive of f(x) iff $g'(x)=f(x)$». When this is true we may write $\int f(x)=g(x)$.

Now, knowing that the differential of $y=f(x)$ is $dy=f'(x)dx\Leftrightarrow \int dy =\int f'(x)dx $. 
I would like to know how I can with this notation deduce that $\int dy = y+C$.

I've tried something like : $\int dy = \int 1 dy= w(y)$, where $w'(y)=1dy \Leftrightarrow w(y)=y+c(x)$, and $c(x)$ is a function of $x$ and constant in $y$. But with this last part I don't seem to reach what I would like to, namely
$y+C=\int f'(x)dx$, where $C$ is a constant w.r.t. $y$ *and* $x$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You just need the fact that $\int f'(x)dx = f(x) + C$.  Then you've got $\int dy = \int f'(x)dx = f(x)+C=y+C$.

Comment: @Bye_World But isn't that what I'm trying to prove?

Comment: What does $\int f(x)dx$ mean to you?  Isn't it just an antiderivative?

Comment: @Bye_World I'm thinking the antiderivative as the inverse of the derivative, not the differential. This means that  $\int f'(x)=f(x)+c$. That's why I'm trying to understand differentials. It seems that we may give a meaning to $dx$ with the concept of differentials. I'm trying to conciliate both notations in my head...

Comment: $\int f'(x)$ doesn't mean anything.  Either you can take $\int f'(x)dx := f(x) + C$ as a definition or you can think of the integrand $f'(x)dx$ as a [differential form](http://www.math.purdue.edu/~dvb/preprints/diffforms.pdf) and the mapping $\int$ as taking an **exact** form $d\alpha$ to the class of functions $\alpha + C$.

Comment: Thanks. maybe that's my confusion... the book I'm using said that we could use that notation for antiderivative. ;)